# jQuery .mouseenter not working with absolute positioning.

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a new website. I've done the basic layout. I'm trying to keep to the strict HMTL5 standards so I'm using lots of CSS3 tricks. also at the moment it only targets 'modern' browsers. I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't select any of the menu items? I'm trying to use jquery's mouse enter mouseexit functions on the

tag. 
I've uploaded it to my site [benjaminbriggs.co.uk](http://benjaminbriggs.co.uk/09123120484120/). Any help would be great. I just what to know where I'm going wrong. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the CSS rule `z-index: 10;` to your `nav` and try.

At the moment, your main `section` has gone above the `nav`. so using z-index would do the trick.

Furthermore add this to see if the hover is working properly for the list items so you know it is accessible.

```
nav li:hover{
   background: #f00;
}
```